# ssl certificates for *.subdomain.example.com

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, https, certificate, wildcard

I plan on getting a wildcard certificate for my domain like *.example.com, but I've heard varying reports about whether it will also work with second-level subdomains like *.subdomain.example.com -- reports that it works in Firefox but not in other browsers.

If I want it to work with all browsers, will I need to purchase a wildcard certificate for *.subdomain.example.com?

Is there a place for more definitive information on how this works and with what browsers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matching in wildcard certificates is done on a level-by-level basis, so if you want a certificate that will work for `foo.sub.example.com` as well as `bar.example.com`, you need a certificate that has alt names of both `*.sub.example.com` and `*.example.com`.  If you wanted to also match `baz.xyzzy.example.com` you'd then need `*.*.example.com` (instead of `*.sub.example.com`).  It all gets rather unpleasant, and you'd probably need to have a thorough chat with (and a phat checkbook for) your SSL certificate provider, as I can't imagine it's something they deal with daily.

Answer (score 3):

You either need to get separate wildcard certificates for each level, or have your SSL provider put in multiple levels or specific hostnames as SANs in the wildcard certificate for *.example.com (if you can find a provider to do this).